# Apple.com Search like Transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I would like to make my search bar transition like Apple.com's and I have read many of the posts online about it. I am currently using CSS to hide and show elements to create the search bar. But the search bar outline and the search bar background (white) are still showing. I would like to show nothing except for the search glyphicon (just like apple.com). It is a bit difficult since the glyphicon is shown as a background image inside the input box.

Do I need JS to fully achieve the behavior? Or is there some way to render the rest of the input box invisible?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control search left rounded" id="search-bar" placeholder="search" ng-model="search.name"></input>
```

CSS:

```
.search {
    width:360px;
    position:relative; top:2px; 
    padding:8px 5px 8px 30px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:white url(http://i.imgur.com/lFkqn.png) left center no-repeat;
}

#search input {
 /*background: none;*/
 /*opacity: 0.1;*/
 width: 30px !important;
 -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
 transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
 border: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none !important;
    -moz-appearance:none !important;
    appearance:none !important;

}
#search input:focus {
  /*opacity: 0.9;*/
 width: 200px !important;
 -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
 transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
 border: default !important;
 background: default !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need with css3 only.

```
.search {
    width:30px;
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    padding:8px 5px 8px 30px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:white url(http://i.imgur.com/lFkqn.png) left center no-repeat;
      -moz-transition: width 0.5s linear !important;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s linear !important;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
}
#search input {
    /*background: none;*/
    /*opacity: 0.1;*/
    width: 30px !important;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-out !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none !important;
    -moz-appearance:none !important;
    appearance:none !important;
}
.search:focus {
    /*opacity: 0.9;*/
    width: 200px !important;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
    border: default !important;
    background: default !important;
}

<input type="text" class="form-control search left rounded" id="search-bar" placeholder="search" ng-model="search.name"></input>
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. Now the search bar doesn't respond to even a click. Perhaps a fiddle could prove this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body{
          background-color: #fff;
          }
     .search input.search-text{
          height: 30px;
          border: 0;
          color: #555;
          margin: 0 auto;
          width:25px;
          background:white url(http://i.imgur.com/lFkqn.png) left center no-repeat;
          transition: width 700ms ,background 700ms;    
          -webkit-transition: width 700ms ,background 700ms;
          -moz-transition: width 700ms ,background 700ms;
          -ms-transition: width 700ms ,background 700ms;
          -o-transition: width 700ms ,background 700ms;

           box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #444;
          -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #444;
          -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #444;
          -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #444;
          -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #444;



      } 
       .search input.search-text:focus{
            background-color: #e1f0f3;
            width:450px;




       }

   </style>
 </head>
    <body>
      <center>
       <div class="search">
          <input class="search-text" type="text" />
       </div>
     </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made a fiddle for this code so please check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/simonzhu91/6osuzz4e/ It doesnt seem to work however, you can still see the borders and the icon is surrounded by white space in the search bar. I want to place this search bar in my gray navbar so the white background will appear. Is there anyway to avoid the white background (make it transparent?)

Comment: Few Changes width:0px;
 padding-left:30px;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/narayana_85/6osuzz4e/8/ Check this  for transparent you need to this                                           `background:transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/lFkqn.png) left center no-repeat;`

Comment: Yes this is what i needed. I cannot believe it was something so simple as "background: transparent". Thanks! =)